# Button not removed after its superview is removed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a `button` in `timingView`, the button itself shows time left when a timer is started:

```
func startTiming(button: UIButton, duration: Double, timingView: UIView?) {

    var duration = duration
    button.setTitle(String(Int(duration)), for: .normal)
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) {_ in
        if duration > 0 {
            duration -= 1
            button.setTitle(String(Int(duration)), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
        timer.invalidate()
        if timingView != nil {
            timingView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

And `timingView` gets removed whenever user taps `button` during timing:

```
func cancelAbilityTiming(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.superview!.superview!.removeFromSuperview()

    // remove timingView from superview
}
```

I was expecting `timingView` and all of its subviews get removed every time the timer is canceled, however, if I cancel a timer then restart it, there'll be 2 timers going on the same time ( the button label changes twice in a second, to different numbers ), how do I avoid having this?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have placed the button inside the timing view ?

Comment: @MidhunMP yes i did that in interface builder

Comment: Check whether it is placed correctly inside timing view, if possible can you please share the ib tree structure ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Take `timer` as a global variable. Also check if `timer` is `nil` before initializing it. Write `timer = nil` after  `timer.invalidate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't prefer force unwrapping of superview. Instead you can do something like this.

Give a tag to your `timingView` and make sure it's unique in the superview. 
e.g.

```
timingView.tag = 99
```

And make sure `button` is added as a subview of `timingView` if it isn't done through storyboard.

Modify your `cancelAbilityTiming()` to this

```
func cancelAbilityTiming(sender: UIButton) {
    for subview in self.view.subviews {
         if subview.tag == 99 {
             //Removing timingView
             subview.removeFromSuperview()
         }

    }
}
```